# Modulo if statement not producing expected output

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop, modulo

I have coded a math problem prompter. And want to make sure that in the case of division. the outcome is only whole numbers and not being divided by 0. Using the following code.

```
while tries < problems:
    print("What is ....")
    print()
    num1 = random.randint(0,9)
    num2 = random.randint(0,9)
    operation = random.randint(1,4)
    if operation == 1:
        op = '-'
    if operation == 2:
        op = '+'
    if operation == 3:
        op = '/'
        while num2 == 0 or num1%num2 > 0:

               num1 = random.randint(0,9)
               num2 = random.randint(0,9)
```

However. The only problems that are generated are such that the answer is always 1. 0. or the numerator. 
For instance only:
4/1
5/1
6/1
or
0/5
0/6
0/6
or
3/3
2/2
1/1

Comment: Huh, your code works as intended. It is true that the cases you mention will appear more frequently due to the nature of generating numbers within such a small interval, but you can't bypass it unless you increase the size of the random integer generator's interval.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine (beside the indentation of the last 2 lines, but I assume it was changed while copying code).

I ran it in python fiddle with a fixed seed to have a reproducible result:

```
import random

random.seed(21334261)
print("What is ....")
print()
num1 = random.randint(0,9)
num2 = random.randint(0,9)
print("num1: {} \n num2: {}".format(num1, num2))
operation = 3
if operation == 1:
    op = '-'
if operation == 2:
    op = '+'
if operation == 3:
    op = '/'
    while num2 == 0 or num1%num2 > 0:  
        num1 = random.randint(0,9)
        num2 = random.randint(0,9)

print("num1: {} \n num2: {}".format(num1, num2))
```

I get as output 8 and 4.

My guess is that it is just a matter of probability: your condition will always be true with num2=1 or if num1=0.

On the other hand there are only a handful of other cases that work and do not fall in the categories you described: 9/3 8/4 8/2 6/3 6/2 4/2.

Edit: corrected the indentation of the while block, thanks to MaximTitarenko.

Comment: The indentation of the last `while` block is correct since, as it follows from the question: `in the case of division. the outcome is only whole numbers and not being divided by 0`, the OP wants to inplement it only for the division `operation == 3`

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense! Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I'm not 100% on this, but my results do show several instances of actual problems, ex 3,6,7,9, but the ones like you described are just much more likely to occur, and when you run it with random operations as well, your chances of getting the fairly rarer real division problems goes way down

```
1 num1 0 num2 4
2 num1 3 num2 3
3 num1 6 num2 3
4 num1 4 num2 4
5 num1 4 num2 4
6 num1 6 num2 2
7 num1 8 num2 2
8 num1 5 num2 1
9 num1 8 num2 2
10 num1 6 num2 1
11 num1 0 num2 6
12 num1 3 num2 3
13 num1 5 num2 5
14 num1 6 num2 2
15 num1 4 num2 1
16 num1 9 num2 1
17 num1 0 num2 5
18 num1 0 num2 8
19 num1 0 num2 1
```